# Mistake in the prononciation of surah al fatiha

Tags: salat, waswasa, mistake, surat-al-fatihah, meaning

Assalam ´aleykoum,
I think that sometimes I may have pronounce « … na’budu’a… » instead of « … na’budu wa… » in the fifth verse of Surah Al Fatiha. Does that change the meaning? Should I repeat my prayer if I realize this error and the time of the prayer is not over? Should I make up the other prayers from previous days where I may have make this mistake.

Answer (score -3):

I think it not problem If you are cannot pronounce Arabic correctly

you can check how to prononce نعبد
using google translate and paste

```
اياك نعبد و اياك نستعين
```